# Selenium entering invalid text (Half text) in text box

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, automated-tests

While running multiple test cases, selenium is entering invalid text as shown in the attachment.
Below are the two Examples showing the error:

1. Instead of entering AutomationTest123_6035633258972, it just enters    6035633258972. [image: Example1].
2. Instead of Entering AutomationTest123_636010703068635512, it just
   enters utomationTest123_636010703068635512. [image: Example2] .

---

**Code**

```
   //StaticVariable is class which has static values
   var username = StaticVariable.username;
   var password = StaticVariable.password;
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(username); //putting wrong values
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(password); //putting wrong values
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();
```

Can anyone help me on this? Any help would appreciated.

Comment: can you share your automation code ?

Comment: @selva have updated the code.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you output the StaticVariable.username to the log to be sure the problem doesn't lie elsewhere?

Comment: @Nibb The output of the StaticVariable.username gives the correct value in the logs.

Comment: Are you able to enter the same text for username and password manually in your application without using Selenium? Just to make sure your app is not trimming those characters!!

Comment: @harish yes, if i type these characters manually then the application is working fine.

Comment: This is indeed a problem, even I experienced this issue in my project. In one of the textbox it is entering partial text to what I'm sending and in anther one it is just trying to add to an existing value, for ex. the text box has value 25, I'm sending clear() command and then trying to set 29, it sets the value to 295. When debugged, I can see the text getting cleared with Clear() call, so something is wrong while entering the value it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clear` method then type the text: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("").clear();`

It may help.

Comment: Be sure to format code as code so that it more recognizable and properly formatted. You can read the editing/formatting help topics but for code the easiest way to do this is to put 4 spaces in front of code.

Comment: @Arun I tried this, but the results are same, its entering half text value.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure that

```
var username = StaticVariable.username;
```

is assigning the right value.
use a

```
print
```

to check what the value of username after assign.

than try by using the below code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).click()
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).clear()
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(username);
```

Comment: You realize that you are scraping the page 3 times to run this code? If you are going to use an element 2 or more times, just store it in a variable and reference it. It will not only make execution faster, it's more maintainable. If that ID changes, you will have to update it in 3 places.

Comment: @noor I tried this but its not working the result is same, its entering half text.

Comment: @JeffC yup, got it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple of reasons I've seen that this can be an issue. I'd first try to clear out the text input first and make sure it has focus.

```
var username = StaticVariable.username;
var password = StaticVariable.password;
// Fill out user name
var userElem = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
userElem.click();
userElem.clear();
userElem.sendKeys(userName);
// Fill out password
var passElem = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
passElem.click();
passElem.clear();
passElem.sendKeys(password);
// Click login button
driver.findElement(By.id("login"))
      .click();
```

If, however, that doesn't fix it, I've had situations where splitting the string up and sending keys a few at a time has worked. That **does** have a performance penalty so I wouldn't do it unless you really really need to.

```
public void fooTest() {
    // Do stuff to get to the correct page, etc
    var username = StaticVariable.username;
    var password = StaticVariable.password;
    // Fill out user name
    var userElem = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    sendKeys(userElem, userName);
    // Fill out password
    var passElem = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    sendKeys(passElem, password);
    // Click login button
    driver.findElement(By.id("login"))
          .click();
    // do assertions, etc
}

private void sendKeys(WebElement elem, String keys) {
    elem.click();
    elem.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i) {
        elem.sendKeys(keys.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Note : sorry for any syntax / c# errors, I've barely used the language ... I'm much more familiar with Java ;-)

Comment: I tried this but its not working the result is same, its entering half text.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 'var' , you might want to try putting in the specific type , such as 'string'.  The problem has to be in what is being passed to .SendKeys() or how it is being received by the function.

```
string username = StaticVariable.username;
string password = StaticVariable.password;
```